# I need help, my code is giving trouble public bool EhAprovado() { if (_mediafinal > 7 && _quantidadefaltas < 15) { return true; } }

Tags: c#

I'm having problems with my boolean code, can anyone help me?

```
public bool EhAprovado()
{  
    if (_mediafinal > 7 && _quantidadefaltas < 15)
    {
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. This is an English website. Please edit your question to English. Also have a look at [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Take The Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how to post proper questions. In its current state this question is most likely to get downvoted and closed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not written in English.

Comment: Good. Now that it is in English please follow the links of How To Ask so to correct this question and make it clear for what you are asking. (Please also give a proper title) Also if you get any compilation errors - have you googled? What have you found?

Answer (score 1):

all return method need to return thing so If you create bool method need to return result for else Like this :

```
public bool EhAprovado()
{  
    if (_mediafinal > 7 && _quantidadefaltas < 15)
   return true;
   else
   return false;
}
```

I hope it help you

Comment: Though is could solve the question it is advised to wait until question is clarified and is proper before answering (and especially as this question is most likely a duplicate)

Comment: oh i don't know sorry